# Remove/Find Nodes in hierarchical table of JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, jpql

I have created a table to store hierarchical data for a purpose.
In LEAF column Its there to decide whether its a leaf. And PARENT_ID column is for checking which one is the parent of the node. Below is the Database Table.

```
CREATE TABLE info
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  leaf bigint,
  "name" character varying(255),
  parent_id bigint,
  "value" character varying(255),
  "info" character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT info_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

TABLE NAME: info

```
ID LEAF  NAME PARENT_ID VALUE  INFO
-- ----  ---- ------    -----  ----
1   0    ROOT  0        ''     '' 
2   0     S2   1        ''     ''
3   0     S3   1        TEST1  INFO1
4   1     S4   1        TEST2  ''
5   1     S5   2        ''     ''
6   0     S6   3        ''     ''
8   1     S8   6        P8     ''
```

I'm using JPA Hibernate with PostgreSQL in my project, this is the only table with data. and it has no relation to any other table.

**Q1)** If I want to delete "S3" how should I do that, since It has "S6" as a child and "S8" is a child of "S6". So It needs to be cascaded on update when I delete "S3". How can I do this in JPQL or Hibernate NativeQuery in JAVA?

**Q2)** How can I find children and leaf of a specific Parent Node?

Comment: For Q1, I think if you set it to cascade delete in the Parent reference, it would delete the children as well.  For Q2, I don't know how to do it, but I think what you are looking for is a "hierarchical query".  This may help in Google'ing.  I did something like this once before in plan-ol' Hibernate, but its been a long time and I don't have the reference any more.

Comment: how do I set cascade delete to this table since its the only table i have? can u give a sample? @CodeChimp

Comment: You don't set it on the table, you set it in your Entity, either by using `@CascadeOnDelete` or by setting the `cascadeType={CascadeType.DELETE}` in your relationship annotation (`@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne`, etc)

Comment: Inorder to put '@OneToMany' or '@ManyToOne' I have to have another entity, question is im only having one entity that equals one table(shown above)

Comment: No, you can have an `@OneToMany` that points to the same Entity/table.  I did this when I had to represent a tree structure with nodes, so I know that's possible.  All you have to do to support it is be able to tell JPA how the relationship is wired together so it can do the appropriate selecting.  That's what I assumed you were doing here, since you mentioned parent and children nodes.  Source code examples would have maybe helped me understand better what you were doing, or trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a recursive [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html) (CTE).

I don't know if JPQL exposes that functionality, but a straight up native query for your situation would look like this (which gives all descendants of S3):

```
with recursive parents
as
(
  select "ID", "NAME", "PARENT_ID"
  from test
  where "NAME" = 'S3'

  union all

  select b."ID", b."NAME", b."PARENT_ID"
  from parents a
         join test b
           on a."ID" = b."PARENT_ID"
)
select *
from parents
;
```

Keep in mind that that query assumes there are no loops in your data - read through the link for hints on dealing with that situation.

Comment: when i run your query it gives 0 rows retrieved

Comment: this returns children with the parent, i need to have only the children to display

Comment: How about adding a "where NAME != S3" on to the main "select * from parents" query?